# The cli options in the Typeorm config is not working

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am learning about migrations in NestJs typeorm so when i specfied the cli property to typeormconfig file it says that the cli property dont exist.

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions  } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { join } from 'path';

const typeConfigDatabase: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  entities: [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')],
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: ['dist/src/db/migrations/*.js'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/db/migrations',
  },
};
```

I was expecting that on running the migration command the migration folder will be created but its not.
The Error is :

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'cli' does not exist in type '{ retryAttempts?: number; retryDelay?: number; toRetry?: (err: any) => boolean; autoLoadEntities?: boolean; keepConnectionAlive?: boolean; verboseRetryLog?: boolean; } &
```

Comment: Whats your `@nestjs/typeorm` version?

Comment: I am using version 10.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `typeorm` version of `0.3` or higher, the `cli.migrationsDir` option do not exist anymore.

You'll have to use the new way to generate migrations: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8810

---

Basically, you need to have two options in typeorm config:

1. `migrationsTableName`
2. `migrations`

Then use the CLI to create the migration:

```
typeorm migration:create ./path-to-migrations-dir/PostRefactoring
```

Refer to https://typeorm.io/migrations#creating-a-new-migration for more details.